# Modifying Permissions vs Root Script Execution. What's Better?

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts

After every suspend, When I wake up my laptop, it never connects to any network and have to restart NetworkManager again. So, out of laziness I wrote this [script](https://ghostbin.com/paste/zo8ja) that works fine as expected.

I have used an `if` block to check that the script is always executed by the root user:

```
if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "ERROR : Root Priveleges Required"                                                                                       
    exit NOT_ROOT                                                                                                                 

else                                                                                                                                  
    netrestart                                                                                                                
fi
```

And I gave this script this permission (being root when executing this command):

```
chmod u+x netrestart
```

Now, When I run this script as a non-root user, it shows this

```
bash: ./netrestart: Permission denied
```

And then, running script with `sudo` runs fine

```
sudo ./netrestart
```

I think that makes the root check in the script useless. Now I have 2 questions:

1. Shall I remove that part of code or still use in the script?
2. What's better and how?

   - Checking if user is root inside the script and giving execute permissions to everyone, i.e., `chmod 755 netrestart`
   - Setting the right needed permissions on script itself and not including the check for if user is root inside the script, i.e., `chmod 711 netrestart`

Comment: Better in which sense? Why not add `sudo` to the relevant commands and remove all those checks and give permissions to everybody? Also, `service NetworkManager restart ` might be better than killing and manually starting.

Comment: Sure, I will write `Service NetworkManager restart` instead . And also I don't exactly know in which sense. I just want to know If there are any cons and pros regarding performance, security or some other stuff that I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I think your script can be condensed to:

```
#!/bin/bash

NOT_ROOT=2
sudo service network-manager restart || exit $NOT_ROOT
if service network-manager status
then
    echo "Successfully Restarted NetworkManager"
else
    echo "ERROR : Failed to work"
    exit 1
fi
```

`sudo` will check for root access for you and prompt if necessary. The `service ... status` check will more reliably tell you if NetworkManager started up normally.

You can grant this execute permissions on this script to everyone, and `sudo` will take care of permission checks.

Comment: I changed my script to what you suggested. It works awesome. Thanks !

Comment: `/bin/bash` is not needed here, `/bin/sh` would suffice. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh for the differences.